# How to authenticate users and get an authentication token based on REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

How can I authenticate users and get an authentication token based on REST API on a wordpress website?
Then how can I use that token to update some content on my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally used [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) plugin to allow me to authenticate users and get an authentication token.

Using postman you can send a POST request containing  json value=`{"username":"yourUserName","password":"yourPassword"}` to the following endpoint to get the token:

```
http://yourdomain.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token
```

then you can update wordpress site content using that token. for example to update a post title you can send a POST request containing Bearer token as Authorization header and json value=`{"title":"new title"}` as body to the following endpoint:

```
http://yourdomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1
```